# Can one Controller share data to other Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In one of my `Controllers` Action Method I get the current week number and it's passed to the `View`. I realize that I could need the week number in other `Controllers` and `Views`, but I don't want to copy/paste the same code at different places in my project.

I'm looking for a simple and smart solution where I can reuse the code from just one place like a static class or a global object or something similar. If it was within the same `Controller` I could have done a method to call, but since I need it from other `Controllers`, I need another solution and I'm not sure how to achieve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Put the code in a class, use that class in each controller.

Comment: Create a BaseController with protected method(s) containing your 'shared' code and derive your other controllers from it.

Comment: Small code examples are always welcome to understand it better :)

Comment: Inheritance https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx

Comment: @StephenMuecke But isn't the Controllers already derived from Controller class and if also should dirive another Controller I need an Interface or have I misunderstod your solution?

Comment: @CodeCaster OK, do you mean a simple class that is static

Comment: `BaseController : Controller` (with common methods) and `XController : BaseController`, `YController : BaseController` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Normally, I'm right there with you, but I couldn't disagree more with implementing a base controller for this.

Comment: @ChrisPratt What solution do you suggest?

Comment: @ChrisPratt, Just one of many possible answers (depends on the use case)

Comment: What @CodeCaster said. Create a class and utilize that class wherever you need this functionality.

Comment: @ChrisPratt OK, Then I do a class! Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't help that your question is quite abstract and lacking details. Do you mean you want to calculate one value for one user once, and reuse it for the entire session for that user? Then you could simply initialize it once and store it in the session. Also, you're asking for code, but not showing any.

Comment: @CodeCaster A session is a good idea! No, I'm not showing any code! What code should I show!?

Comment: The code which you don't want to repeat for every controller, and the controller that contains it, for example.

Comment: @CodeCaster OK, but since everyone knows how a Controller looks like and the code that I don't want to repeat can be any kind of code that has a value that could be used at several places, I thought it was unnecessary to include this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that inherits from Controller.

I create a BaseController class like so:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected someDBContext db = new someDBContext();
    protected User currentUser;
    public static ILog ErrorLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("ErrorLogger");

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            currentUser = UserToStaff.GetCurrentUser(
                (int)Session["userId"],
                db
            );
        }

        ViewBag.currentUser = currentUser;

        addNoticesToViewBag();

    }..
```

I add functions and properties for common tasks like 
creating the dbContext, creating the currentUser object, and setting up logging in here.

Don't let it grow arms and legs though.. the Initialize is going to fire with every request.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the solution with a session is better.